# Are variables kept in memory after the class has been initialized?

Tags: python, class, oop

If I defined a class

```
class myclass:

    def __init__(self, variable):    
        a = variable * 100
        self.a = a*1000
```

and I created an instance of the `myclass` object

```
myinstance = myclass([1])
```

After initialization, does python still keep `a` in it's memory? or does it only store `self.a`?

Comment: No, `a` is a local variable, and it ceases to exist after the function terminates

Comment: In addition to what @juanpa.arrivillaga said: the variable (or rather the object, that your variable name is pointing to) will be flagged for garbage collection, since no other variable names are referencing it once the function terminates. So it may be kept in memory for a little, until the garbage collector decides to free the memory.

Comment: @MikeScotty indeed, in CPython objects are reclaimed *immediately* when their reference count reaches 0, but that is an implementation detail